# SQL: Select only 1st row from lexical ordered table

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

### In a nutshell

How can you speed up this statement (running on a table with very much rows)?:

```
select * from mytable where val2=4 order by key1, key2, key3 limit 1;
```

---

### In detail

This is my table (here displayed sorted lexically by its three keyfields) from which I want to select the one row that I have marked with an arrow. There are 3 fields in the primary index: key1, then key2, then key3.

Know that my real table has more columns and about 100,000 rows (and an index on column val2).

```
key1 | key2 | key3 | val1 | val2
-----+------+------+------+------
   2 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    1 
   3 |    1 |    0 |    2 |    2 
   3 |    2 |    0 |    3 |    3 
   3 |    2 |    1 |    1 |    4  <==
   4 |    1 |    0 |    2 |    5 
   4 |    2 |    0 |    3 |    1 
   4 |    2 |    1 |    1 |    2 
   4 |    3 |    0 |    2 |    3 
   4 |    3 |    1 |    3 |    4 
   4 |    3 |    2 |    1 |    5 
   5 |    1 |    0 |    2 |    1 
   5 |    2 |    0 |    3 |    2 
   5 |    2 |    1 |    1 |    3 
   5 |    3 |    0 |    2 |    4 
   5 |    3 |    1 |    3 |    5 
   5 |    3 |    2 |    1 |    1 
   5 |    4 |    0 |    2 |    2 
   5 |    4 |    1 |    3 |    3 
   5 |    4 |    2 |    1 |    4 
   5 |    4 |    3 |    2 |    5
```

This is the statement that exactly delivers the wanted row, and also explains what I want in detail:

```
select * from mytable where val2=4 order by key1, key2, key3 limit 1;
```

I want to do this (in sequential pseudocode):

```
1. Select all rows which have the value 4 in field val2.
2. Sort those rows by key1, then by key2, then by key3
3. Return only the first single row of this sorted set of rows
```

My select statement needs to read the whole table, and then has to sort a huge amount of rows before it can find the one row that I want.

I think this could be done quicker with nested subselects (i know this syntax is wrong, but I hope you understand what i want to do):

```
select * from mytable where key1+key2+key3 = (
    select key1, key2, min(key3) from mytable where val2=4 and key1+key2 = (
        select key1, min(key2) from mytable where val2=4 and key1 = (
            select min(key1) from mytable where val2=4
        )
    )
)
```

But I don't know how to write this in a correct sql syntax, and I'm not sure if this really is a better way. I think, there must be an elegant solution using joins (joining a table with itself), but I can't find such an solution.

Can you help, please?

---

### EDIT (after comments)

Ok, let's talk about my real table:

At the moment, there is only one row in this table, and it has not 3 but 2 key-fields. But this table will grow in an iterative process, where one row has to be selected using the statement we are discussing about now. This row will be processed, and as a result of this process, this row will be updated. Plus: Between 0 and 2 new rows will be inserted. Then it repeats: A new row will be selected, analyzed and updated, and again between 0 and 2 new rows will be inserted.

At the beginning this process will add lots of new rows, that need to be read later. At the end hopefully this process stops, because there are no more rows that match to the WHERE-clause. Then the remaining rows have to be analyzed.

So, this are the statements that create the table and insert the starting-row:

```
CREATE TABLE `numbers` (
  `a0` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `b0` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `n` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `an` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bn` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `m` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gele` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '?'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `numbers` (`a0`, `b0`, `n`, `an`, `bn`, `m`, `gele`) VALUES
(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '?');

ALTER TABLE `numbers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`a0`,`b0`),
  ADD KEY `gele` (`gele`);
```

Here is my statement:

```
SELECT `a0`, `b0`, `n`, `an`, `bn`, `m`, `gele`
FROM `numbers`
WHERE `gele` = '?' OR `gele` = '='
ORDER BY `a0`, `b0`
LIMIT 1;
```

And this is the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT ....`:

```
id | select_type | table   | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra  
 1 | SIMPLE      | numbers | NULL       | index  | gele          | PRIMARY |       8 | NULL | 1    | 100.00   | Using where
```

Since there is only 1 row in the table at the moment, the result of the explain statement is not very helpful, sorry.

But anyway: I want a more generic answer to this problem, because it occurs very often.

Comment: Trust the optimizer in this case.

Comment: Before you being manually optimising the statement, how does it currently perform (time) and over how many rows? What indexes do you have? And if you can add the output of the execution plan to your question, that would help.

Comment: As a minimum, questions of this sort always require the following: 1) CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables. 2) The results of the EXPLAIN.

Comment: @Strawberry: I updated my question.

Comment: I thought it would make no difference, but if I replace index gele(gele) with index gele(gele,a0,b0) then the task completes 4 times faster (0.07 secs vs. 0.27 secs on a data set of ca. 120,000 rows). The explain is also very slightly different.

Comment: @Strawberry: Thank you! That might help a lot!

Comment: I don't think so.  In InnoDB, the PK columns are appended to each secondary index.  Hence, `INDEX(gele)` is the same as `INDEX(gele, a0, b0)`.  The timing difference is _probably_ due to caching -- that is, less I/O was necessary on the faster one.  Run each query twice to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, regardless of how the records are laid out on disk, you *must* use `ORDER BY` to guarantee the order of records from a `SELECT`.  The Optimizer will (usually) notice the order of the records and can decide to do 'nothing' for the `ORDER BY`.

In InnoDB, records are arranged according to the `PRIMARY KEY`.  So, given `PRIMARY KEY (a0,b0)` and `ORDER BY a0, b0`, the Optimizer *may* simply read the rows in order without having to do a sort.

But...  If you have a `WHERE` clause that, say, says `WHERE c0 > 3` and you have `INDEX(c0, b0)`, the Optimizer is *likely* to use the index for filtering, then have to sort, even if you say `ORDER BY a0, b0`.  This is likely to be faster than doing a table scan (to avoid the sort) and filter as it steps through all the rows (to perform the `WHERE`).

Your

1. Select all rows which have the value 4 in field val2.
2. Sort those rows by key1, then by key2, then by key3
3. Return only the first single row of this sorted set of rows

is very simply, and very efficiently, done via

```
INDEX(val2, key1, key2, key3)

SELECT ...
    WHERE val2 = 4                -- filter column goes first
    ORDER BY key1, key2, key3     -- sort columns next
    LIMIT 1
```

It will read exactly one 'row' from that composite index, then look up the row in the data (using the `PRIMARY KEY`).  Both are "point queries", using a BTree index.  We are talking a few milliseconds, even if nothing is cached, regardless of table size.

See [*my cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) on building indexes.

But your 'real' query is *not* the same pattern; it has an 'OR'

```
SELECT  `a0`, `b0`, `n`, `an`, `bn`, `m`, `gele`
    FROM  `numbers`
    WHERE  `gele` = '?'
       OR  `gele` = '='
    ORDER BY  `a0`, `b0`
    LIMIT  1;
```

`INDEX(gele, a0, b0)` is tempting, but it won't work.  All the `'?'` values are nicely ordered according to `a0, b0`, and so are the `'='` values.  But you want both sets.  This involves "merging" two sorted lists.  The Optimizer has a way to do it, but it is rarely worth the effort.  It turns out that there are two possibly 'best' indexes, and the Optimizer cannot always decide correctly between them:

```
INDEX(gele)  -- do all the filtering; sort later
INDEX(a0,b0) -- avoids sorting, but requires reading an indeterminate number of rows
```

Since the latter is your PK, and there is some advantage in using the PK, that is what the Optimizer picked.  If no '?' nor '=' occurs until the 'last' row in the table, the query will read the entire table.  :(

One trick that is *sometimes* worth doing is to turn `OR` into `UNION`:

```
    (  SELECT  `a0`, `b0`, `n`, `an`, `bn`, `m`, `gele`
            FROM  `numbers`
            WHERE  `gele` = '?'
            ORDER BY  `a0`, `b0`
            LIMIT  1 )            -- Step 1, below
UNION ALL
    (  SELECT  `a0`, `b0`, `n`, `an`, `bn`, `m`, `gele`
            FROM  `numbers`
            WHERE  `gele` = '='
            ORDER BY  `a0`, `b0`
            LIMIT  1 )            -- Step 2
ORDER BY  a0, b0 -- yes repeated  -- Step 3
LIMIT  1;                         -- Step 4

INDEX(gele, a0, b0)
```

This is guaranteed to be fast, but it has some overhead:

1. Search for '?' -- find the row promptly.  Write to tmp table.
2. Search for '=' -- find the row promptly.  Append to tmp table.
3. Sort the tmp table.
4. Peel off 1 row.

Yes, there is a 'temp' table and 'filesort', but with only 2 rows, it is very fast.  This particular formulation works fast regardless of the table size.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me understand what is going on, and helps me to solve similar problem in the future!

Comment: That's my goal.

Answer (score 0):

From the information provided, it's hard to say if there is a better way.

Given your query:

```
select * from mytable where val2=4 order by key1, key2, key3 limit 1;
```

The `WHERE` clause will first restrict the rows to only those containing `val2 = 4` before the rest *have to be* sorted to get the ordering you require.

Even though you only want one row, you have to sort all the data.

Only the inclusion of an index on the `val2` field will speed up the `WHERE` part of this. Other than that, you are at the mercy of the optimiser and the speed of your hardware.

Comment: I do not believe, that every row has to be read. Using the indexes, you can find the matching key1 (select min(key1) from mytable where val2=4) knowing the value of key1 you can find key2 with a similar select, and so on for all keys. You just need to read indexes to get the complete keys. Having them, you can make a single-row-select. No need to read all the table. (btw: I've updated my question)

Comment: With `INDEX(val2, key1, key2, key3)`, _only one row_ need be read.

Comment: @RickJames - You are correct, but I answered this question when there was no information about the table or indexes and Hubert was asking how to rewrite a SQL statement in order to improve the query speed.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast - I never said all rows from the table would be read. After the `WHERE` clause filters the table the _remaining_ rows would have to be sorted. Of course, since you have added more information it has been possible for Rick to provide a better answer; from which I've learnt as well :)

Comment: @Tony - Please edit your Answer to reflect the OP's edit.  This will prevent confusion by future users.